# Pairwise distance between collections of points with latitude and longitude

Tags: python, performance, geospatial, geopy

I have two sets of points with their latitudes and longitudes, and I want to calculate the pairwise distance between them. This works when the two lists are small:

```
from geopy.distance import distance

c1 = [(-34.7102, -58.3853),
     (-32.9406, -60.7136),
     (-34.6001, -58.3729),
     (-38.9412, -67.9948),
     (-35.1871, -59.0968)]

c2 = [(-43.2568, -65.2853),
     (-31.4038, -64.1645),
     (-34.7634, -58.2120),
     (-34.4819, -58.5828),
     (-34.5669, -58.4515),
     (-34.6356, -68.369),
     (-34.4048, -58.6896)]

distances = []
for c in c1:
    this_row = [distance(c, x).meters for x in c2]
    distances.append(this_row)
```

However, the actual lengths of `c1` and `c2` are 50000 and 15000, respectively. When I run the above script with my real data, it takes forever. I'm looking for something efficient, such as

```
distances = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(c1, c2)
```

This is very fast, but the function returns the results in a unit that is not specified as far as I know. I'm looking for results in meters.

Is there any way to rewrite the first script in a more efficient way?

Comment: *unit that is not specified as far as I know* - From the docs, [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) returns *the distance between  points using Euclidean distance (2-norm) as the distance metric between the points.* Depending on how precise you need the measurements, you should be able translate the euclidean distance into meters.

Comment: @pault I think that would be possible if distances are small (i.e. the length of a curve around the Earth that links both points is similar to the length of a straight line that goes through the surface). If distances increase, then the conversion is not trivial, at least as I see it.

Comment: @Tendero How does `geopy` calculate the distances without elevation?

Comment: @gmds It uses the shortest distance on the surface of an ellipsoidal model of the earth.

Comment: @Tendero Yes, so what defines that ellipsoid? Anyway, I would suggest that you convert your geodetic coordinates to Cartesian ones (which would require elevation for a precise result), and then use `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`.

Comment: @gmds I think it's the geodesic between two points on a sphere of radius=6371 km (or maybe an ellipsoid as OP says). Anyway, for (not too) large distances, altitude difference becomes almost irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I considered some options. Here's what I learnt, hope this helps:

**[`scipy.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html):**
It seems to accept a callable as `metric` parameter, but I think a custom function will get things slow as well.

**[`scikitlearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html#sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric):**
It has a builtin `haversine` metric.
Anyway, I didn't manage to well understand how to get things working, but I'm sure you'll find a way. Moreover, they claim that, for many metrics, `DistanceMetric.pairwise` will be slower than `scipy.cdist`.

**Projection:**
The only acceptable solution I found implies a projection like [aeqd](https://proj4.org/operations/projections/aeqd.html) of your coordinates on a 2D plane (I'm going to use [`pyproj`](https://pypi.org/project/pyproj/) for this).
This allows you to use `scipy.cdist` on projected points and get things faster, but it will get less precise on pairs too far from a `lat_0, lon_0` coordinate used as a reference for `aeqd` projection (maybe a different projection, or some workaround can solve this).
I posted results from your loop and projection for comparison.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pyproj
import scipy
from geopy.distance import distance

c1 = np.array(
    [(-34.7102, -58.3853),
     (-32.9406, -60.7136),
     (-34.6001, -58.3729),
     (-38.9412, -67.9948),
     (-35.1871, -59.0968)]
    )

c2 = np.array(
    [(-43.2568, -65.2853),
     (-31.4038, -64.1645),
     (-34.7634, -58.2120),
     (-34.4819, -58.5828),
     (-34.5669, -58.4515),
     (-34.6356, -68.369),
     (-34.4048, -58.6896)]
)

# create projections, using a mean (lat, lon) for aeqd
lat_0, lon_0 = np.mean(np.append(c1[:,0], c2[:,0])), np.mean(np.append(c1[:,1], c2[:,1]))
proj = pyproj.Proj(proj='aeqd', lat_0=lat_0, lon_0=lon_0, x_0=lon_0, y_0=lat_0)
WGS84 = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326')

# transform coordinates
projected_c1 = pyproj.transform(WGS84, proj, c1[:,1], c1[:,0])
projected_c2 = pyproj.transform(WGS84, proj, c2[:,1], c2[:,0])
projected_c1 = np.column_stack(projected_c1)
projected_c2 = np.column_stack(projected_c2)

# calculate pairwise distances in km with both methods
sc_dist = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(projected_c1, projected_c2)
geo_distances = []
for c in c1:
    this_row = [distance(c, x).km for x in c2]
    geo_distances.append(this_row)

print("scipy\n")
print(sc_dist/1000)
print("\n")
print("geopy\n")
print(np.array(geo_distances))
```

Output:

```
scipy

[[1120.68384362  652.43817992   16.93436992   31.1480337    17.02161533
   914.68158465   43.91751967]
 [1212.75267066  367.46344647  307.41739698  261.2734859   276.57111944
   733.44881488  248.25303017]
 [1131.82744423  646.91757042   23.36452322   23.31086804    8.09877062
   916.39849619   36.27486327]
 [ 531.58906215  906.44775882  987.23837525  974.96389103  979.98229079
   479.75111318  971.51078808]
 [1042.57374645  631.42752409   93.47695658   91.28419725   90.64134205
   849.25121659   94.46063802]]


geopy

[[1120.50400287  652.32406273   16.93254254   31.1392657    17.01619952
   914.66757909   43.9058496 ]
 [1212.7494454   367.3591636   307.3468806   261.21313155  276.50708156
   733.28119124  248.19563872]
 [1131.65345927  646.79571942   23.35783766   23.30613446    8.09745879
   916.38027748   36.26700778]
 [ 530.49964531  905.85826336  987.20594883  974.95078113  979.96382386
   478.97343089  971.50158032]
 [1042.44765568  631.37206038   93.47402012   91.2737422    90.63359193
   849.24940173   94.44779778]]
```

Answer (score 2):

`cdist` supports custom distance function, you can pass it like this:

```python
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from geopy.distance import distance as geodist # avoid naming confusion

sc_dist = cdist(c1, c2, lambda u, v: geodist(u, v).meters) # you can choose unit here
```

I'm not sure about the performance though.